# Phonegap File API emptying folder

Tags: android, cordova

Double checking... If the the flag "create" is set to true and "exclusive" is set to false,
will that essentially empty an existing folder  or file at the same path?

So say I have a directory

```
>myDir
    >subDirectory
        -subFile
    -myFile
```

and I run

```
entry.getDirectory("myDir", {create: true, exclusive: false}, success, fail);
```

is that the preferred method of clearing the contents of myDir to

```
>myDir
   [empty]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the folder already exists, setting the `create` flag to false shouldn't empty the files inside. The preferred method of deleting everything from the directory is using `dirEntry.removeRecursively(successCallback, opt_errorCallback);`

An example posted [here on html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-dir) suggest this approach:

```
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
  fs.root.getDirectory('/misc/../music', {}, function(dirEntry) {

    dirEntry.removeRecursively(function() {
      console.log('Directory removed.');
    }, errorHandler);

  }, errorHandler);
}, errorHandler);
```